# Docker Nginx Angular2/Angular routes

Tags: angular, nginx, docker, nginx-location

I have an Angular2/Angular app running inside a docker container and using nginx to serve it.  So my app base = /myapp/.  Everything works correctly when hitting the app using the base url i.e. www.server.com/myapp or www.server.com/myapp/

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/conf/*.conf;

  server {
    listen       80 default_server;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location /myapp {
      # If you want to enable html5Mode(true) in your angularjs app for pretty URL
      # then all request for your angularJS app will be through index.html
      try_files $uri /myapp/index.html;

    }

    #Static File Caching. All static files with the following extension will be cached for 1 day
    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
      expires 1d;
    }

    ## PROXIES ##
    # location matcher for get requests. Any query params will be proxied using this location block
    location = /myapp/api {

      proxy_pass http://$hostname/api$is_args$query_string;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_connect_timeout       120;
      proxy_send_timeout          120;
      proxy_read_timeout          120;
      send_timeout                120;
    }

    # location matcher for post requests i.e. updateAsset. Any request with additional path params will be proxied using this location block
    location ~ ^/myapp/api/(?<section>.*) {

      proxy_pass http://$hostname/api/$section;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_connect_timeout       120;
      proxy_send_timeout          120;
      proxy_read_timeout          120;
      send_timeout                120;
    }
  }
}
```

My app has several other routes e.g. /myapp/page1 or /myapp/page2. These routes can be hit when serving the app in dev mode using nodejs.  However once i containerize it (containerization isn't the issue) and serve using nginx then i get a 404 not found when trying to access /myapp/page1 or /myapp/page2.  The error log outputs

`2017/02/27 12:15:01 [error] 5#5: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/myapp/page1" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /myapp/page1 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

I have tried mapping all my app urls in the nginx conf file but nothing seems to work.  How do I get this to work?

Update 1

Added angular routes

Main app route:

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { MyAppComponent } from './index';

export const MyAppRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyAppComponent
  }
];
```

Page 1 route:

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { Page1Component } from './index';

export const Page1Routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path:'page1',
    component: Page1Component
  }
];
```

Comment: Shouldn't location /myapp be location /myapp/ ?

Comment: Works either way.  My issues is I cant get /myapp/page1 to map to my Angular2 route "page1".  this always returns a 404

Comment: Well.. it should redirect everything to index.html, then your router can pick it up. The fact it doesn't do the redirect to /myapp/index.html correctly indicates that the location or the try_files is incorrect. Did you try adding the closing / ?

Comment: Yep tried both.  Both ways worked. Updated the question with the angular routes.  @MikeOne

Comment: I'm not sure now what issue you have. It seems to me your issues are the 404 when you directly try to hit an angular route ('/page1'). If your issue is those 404's, it is a server issue, not an angular issue. You said it worked in dev right?

Comment: Yea it worked in dev OK using nodejs so as you say the Angular routes should be right. Once I serve it using nginx that's when issues arise.

Comment: Your nginx is behaving like there is no `try_files` statement. ISTM `try_files` would not give an `open()` error. Check the configuration with `nginx -T` and ensure that `nginx` has been restarted.

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue but the html base href = <base href="/myapp">.  if i type http://localhost/myapp into my browser then a trailing / is always added

Comment: @RichardSmith ssh'd into the container and the nginx -T output is as described above

Comment: It might have to do with the trailing slashes: Make sure to always add them to both your location and proxy_pass, i.e. `location = /myapp/api/` and `proxy_pass http://$hostname/api$is_args$query_string`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309821/nginx-responding-301-moved-permanently

Answer (score 30):

Here is my nginx sites-available/myapp

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 80 [::]:80;
    root /my/root/path;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;

    location /app1/ {
        alias /my/root/path/app1/;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /app1/index.html;
    }

    location /app2/ {
         ...
    }    
}
```

After setting up the config you want to make your site enabled, run:

```
sudo ln -s /pathtonginx/sites-available/myapp /pathtonginx/sites-enabled/myapp
```

The basehref on my index.html

```
<base href="./">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /app1/index.html;
works like charm

Answer (score 16):

The [`nginx` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) includes a base configuration file, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. This configuration file sets up various items to values that the image maintainers (presumably) know to be good values for a Docker container, so it is tempting to make use of that configuration file as much as possible when serving Angular. Anticipating that users might want to do that, the base configuration file includes the directive

```
http {
...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

so, you can put your Angular specific configuration in a file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/ng.conf`, and get the benefit of using the base configuration file.

That file can be nice and simple. As recommended by [the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) and [the Nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#front-controller-pattern-web-apps), it just uses the [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) to serve your `index.html` for all deep-link paths:

```
  server {
    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
```

and your Dockerfile just needs to copy that file from the build context into the Docker image:

```
COPY src/etc/nginx/conf.d/ng.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

I did that, but it didn't work, because **there is also one snag**.
The `nginx` Docker image also includes a file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. That file is suitable for serving static content (from `/usr/share/nginx/html`), and if Nginx uses that configuration in preference to your configuration (which can happen), your `try_files` will be useless. Your Dockerfile should therefore also remove that default configuration:

```
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your docker file like the following;

```
FROM nginx:1.17.8-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY dist/mooveinn .
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

One important thing is to remove the default nginx conf file.

Then your nginx file will be similar to this one;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    #sending logs to console(standard out) in a predefined json fromat
    #access_log / dev / stdout json_combined;
    #error_log / dev / stdout info json_combined;
    root / usr / share / nginx / html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    include / etc / nginx / mime.types;
    # compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no - cache no - store private auth;
    gzip_types text / plain text / css application / json application / javascript application / x - javascript text / xml application / xml application / xml + rss text / javascript;

    # angular index.html location
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri / /index.html;
    }
    # potential reverse proxy
    for sending api calls
    location / reverse - proxy / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Content - Type application / json;
        proxy_set_header X - Real - IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_pass http: //pointer-api:8080/;
    }
}
```

Build the docker image again, and run the application.